# Async Call back is not working in BeginReceive

Tags: c#, udp, ethernet

Async Callback in BeginReceive function is not working.

Messages are being received in my port. But my code is not able to receive and process the message.

```
 private void StartListening()
    {
        try
        {
            ar_ = udp.BeginReceive(Receive, new object());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    private void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7785);
        byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip);
        string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        AppendTextBox("Received: " + string.Join("-", bytes) + Environment.NewLine);

    }

    public void Send(byte[] MsgBytes)
    {
        try
        {

            UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
            IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtbx_ip.Text), 7785);
            client.Send(MsgBytes, MsgBytes.Length, ip);
            client.Close();
            AppendTextBox("Sent: " + string.Join("-", MsgBytes) + Environment.NewLine);
            StartListening();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppendTextBox("Exception occured: " + ex + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

The Debug point never hits the Receive function after it comes to BeginReceive.
Another information is that, I am using a Static IP in my system. (I am not sure if this is the problem).

Comment: if you are working with async, you should use `Tasks` instead of `voids`, this way you can await your content.

Comment: What is `udp`? The code you have only creates and closes a socket in `Send`

Comment: @Richard I am sending messages via ethernet using UDP protocol. client.Send code is sending the messages. But after listening, Receive is not getting called.

Comment: That doesn't address my question above which was specifically about a field (I assume) that needs a type and initialisation.